# DataTables s.match is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the latest DataTables js: DataTables 1.10.15

But when I use the scrollX attribute it gives me error like :

```
dataTables s.match is not a function
```

Code is simple like:

```
jquery(this).dataTable(
 {
  "scrollX": true
 }
);
```

I also tried 1 and 100% instead of true but I still get the same error.

Also checked: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29887/backwards-incompatibility-scrollx-feature

but not able to solve it.

Comment: `jquery(this).dataTable(` what is `this` ...?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your getting Backwards Incompatibility in the latest versions.

you have to use this DTT settings:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
'scrollX': true
});
$('table').DataTable(data);
```

Comment: What is the difference...?

Answer (score 1):

inAfter upgrading even to 1.10.19 and it didn't help, I've tried to get source (not minified version) of datatables-1.10.19.min.js and what have I seen more clearly:

```
return s.match(/\d$/) ? // line 5839
    s+'px' :
    s;
```

Thinking a bit I've made logically obvious change:

```
return String(s).match(/\d$/) ?
    s+'px' :
    s;
```

And it works for me after that. Which is the lifehack. What can I say? Waiting for fix from DT Team or downloading lib to your server and hacking...